# How to simulate high wire speed ？

Tags: linux, networking, udp, vpn

I want to test the max speed of my VPN(pptp) server, so I plan to download something from one

server by VPN, At first, I think the server need to supply a high speed(30M) for client,  who

can tell me how to do this, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sometimes use iperf to test network bandwidth and speed.  You can grab it at http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/.   Here is a short tutorial on using it: http://openmaniak.com/iperf.php

Comment: PS  If you are going to use this make sure you don't have any firewalls blocking.  IPerf needs to go on both ends.  The firewall thing has tripped me up sometimes